# Beginner Question: How do I access this variable?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, scope, juce

I am learning C++ and JUCE by following tutorials. But I am still stuck on something simple I'm doing. The following is simply a code for a sine wave to be generated based on MIDI data (simple sine synth).

At one point in the code, the volume of the sine wave is set by multiplying by a constant (currently 0.15). I would like to multiple by the value of the level slider (aka. currentLevel or targetLevel or "level.slider.getValue()")

However, I can't figure out how to do this. How do I refer to "level.slider.getValue()" which comes from MainComponentClass while inside "struct SineWaveVoice"?

Is this possible?

Thanks

```
    class LabeledSlider : public GroupComponent

    {
        public:
        LabeledSlider (const String& name)
        {
            setText (name);
            setTextLabelPosition (Justification::centredTop);
            addAndMakeVisible (slider);
        }

        void resized() override
        {
            slider.setBounds (getLocalBounds().reduced (10));
        }

        Slider slider 
        { 
            Slider::RotaryHorizontalVerticalDrag, Slider::TextBoxBelow 
        };


    };

    //==============================================================================
//SINE WAVE PROGRAM

    //==============================================================================
    struct SineWaveVoice : public SynthesiserVoice
    {
        SineWaveVoice() {}

        bool canPlaySound(SynthesiserSound* sound) override
        {
            return dynamic_cast<SineWaveSound*> (sound) != nullptr;
        }

        void startNote(int midiNoteNumber, float velocity,
            SynthesiserSound*, int /*currentPitchWheelPosition*/) override
        {
            currentAngle = 0.0;
            level = velocity * 0.15; ///************** HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO MULTIPLY BY LEVEL SLIDER *******************************
            tailOff = 0.0;

            auto cyclesPerSecond = MidiMessage::getMidiNoteInHertz(midiNoteNumber);
            auto cyclesPerSample = cyclesPerSecond / getSampleRate();

            angleDelta = cyclesPerSample * 2.0 * MathConstants<double>::pi;
        }



        //==============================================================================
//MAINCONTENTCOMPONENT
    //==============================================================================

    class MainContentComponent :    public AudioAppComponent,
                                    private Timer

    {
    public:
        MainContentComponent()
            : synthAudioSource(keyboardState),
            keyboardComponent(keyboardState, MidiKeyboardComponent::horizontalKeyboard)

        {
            LabeledSlider *control = new LabeledSlider("Frequency");
            control->slider.onValueChange = [this] { targetFrequency = frequency.slider.getValue(); };
            control->slider.setTextBoxStyle(Slider::TextBoxBelow, false, 100, 20);
            addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

            control = new LabeledSlider("Level");  //// HERE IS THE LEVEL SLIDER
            control->slider.setRange(0.0, 1.0);
            control->slider.onValueChange = [this] { targetLevel = (float)level.slider.getValue(); };
            addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));


        }


    private:
        double currentSampleRate = 0.0, currentAngle = 0.0, angleDelta = 0.0;
        double currentFrequency = 500.0, targetFrequency = 500.0;
        float currentLevel = 0.1f, targetLevel = 0.1f;
        int rotaryDiam = 100;

        LabeledSlider frequency{ "Frequency" };
        LabeledSlider level{ "Level" };   //// HERE IS THE LEVEL SLIDER AGAIN


        OwnedArray<LabeledSlider> knobs;

        JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (MainContentComponent)
    };
```

Comment: Take out the irrelevant code.

Comment: Okay I deleted everything I think I can. The points I want to work with are still labelled. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use class's variable inside a structure (unless structure is defined inside the class).

Alternatively what you can do is send level.slider.getValue as another parameter in the function wherever the function startNote gets called i.e.

```
void startNote(int midiNoteNumber, float velocity,
    SynthesiserSound*, int levelSlider, int /*currentPitchWheelPosition*/) override
{
    currentAngle = 0.0;
    level = velocity * levelSlider; //Mutliply by the parameter levelSlider
    tailOff = 0.0;

    auto cyclesPerSecond = MidiMessage::getMidiNoteInHertz(midiNoteNumber);
    auto cyclesPerSample = cyclesPerSecond / getSampleRate();

    angleDelta = cyclesPerSample * 2.0 * MathConstants<double>::pi;
}
```

LevelSlider should have the value from the object of MainContentComponent class.

Comment: In principle, that's what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work. I tried adding a line under the public of MainContentComponent: "float levelSlider = level.slider.getValue();". Then I thought I could access this in struct SineWaveVoice by using: "level = velocity * MainContentComponenet::levelSlider". But this does not work still. So I still don't understand how to get that data into where I want it.

Comment: You cannot do this. You cannot use a class' variable in another structure without creating its instance. Either you create class'(MainContentClass) instance in the structure and then use it in the startNote function or create instances of both (class and structure) and use the function declaration stated above.